# How do I create and instantiate a store using VueX called via cdn?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I'm working on a project that's php/vuejs. There's no npm nor yarn nor any tool to install packages so the team members always add the cdn link to everything they need. In this case I need to add Vuex + vuex-persistedstate but I don't get to see how to initiate it and instantiate it... litterally no idea. If somebody could show me where I can find this information or post it here as an answer I will be more than thankful.

I tried this and it didn't work:

vueInstance.js

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    store: store,
...
```

footer.php

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex"></script> 
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex-persistedstate/dist/vuex-persistedstate.umd.js"></script>
<script> Vue.use(Vuex)</script>
```

store.js

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
      count: 0
    },
    mutations: {
      increment (state) {
        state.count++
      }
    }
  })
```

Comment: Look at this [documentation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/installation.html#direct-download-cdn)

Answer (score 0):

i made an example how use `cdn` and `vuex + vuex-persist` (*a simple counter app*)
when you change the count you can see your browser `localStorage` for see changes

and i hope this help you :)

---

#### `important note`:

only use `vuex-persist v2.2.0` the latest version (`v3.1.3`) have problem and show error message in browser.

---

#### you can see it also in codepen: https://codepen.io/Mohamadmasoudi/pen/KKaZMOo

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Vuex - VuexPersist example</title>
</head>
<body>
  
  <div id="app">
    count is: {{count}}
    <button @click="increment">+</button>
    <button @click="decrement">-</button>
  </div>

  <script src="https://vuejs.org/js/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuex-persist@2.2.0"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex@3.6.2/dist/vuex.js"></script>
  <script>

  
  const vuexLocal = new window.VuexPersistence.VuexPersistence({
      storage: window.localStorage,
  });

  const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: { count: 0 },
    mutations: { 
      increment (state) {
        state.count++
      },
      decrement (state) {
        state.count--
      }
    },
    actions: {  },
    plugins: [vuexLocal.plugin]
  });
  
  vm = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    store: store,
    methods: {
      increment(){
        store.commit('increment');
      },
      decrement(){
        store.commit('decrement');
      }
    },
    computed: { 
      count(){
        return store.state.count
      }
    }
  });

  </script>

</body>
</html>
```